# How can I overcome this "Cannot Get /" nginx error?

Tags: node.js, nginx, web-hosting

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to run a node.js app in a "folder" (How do you call it?) of a static HTML site.
I can access my node.js app locally (from http://localhost:3919/), but when I try loading http://mysite.hu/tablafilc, I get this error: `Cannot Get /`.
If I try loading some random page (like http://mysite.hu/asdfasf) however, I get a different error message: `404 not found`. This means something is working, but there is still an error somewhere in my code.

Is this actually impossible? Shoud I try running it from a subdomain intstead?

my */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default* file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.mysite.hu mysite.hu;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /tablafilc {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3919;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ~ ^/(tablafilc|socket\.io) {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3919;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                sub_filter /tablafilc /;
        }
}
```

PS: My static site doesn't have a page called tablafilc. And of course *mysite.hu* is not my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that http://mysite.hu/tablafilc is a GET method?
If it is a POST end point, you cant view it in your browser.

Since you get different responses from your server, I assume that your nginx is working fine.

And btw, it is not a very good practice to change the default file in */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default*.

Comment: Yeah, I think  I'm gonna look at the node files instead..

Comment: Maybe I can find something

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'll maybe try turning off socket.io

Comment: I actually solved the issue by messing around in the config file, and there vas only 4pc of / missing!

Comment: Thx again for the suggestin

Comment: @SamuNemeth can you outline your solution in more detail please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember...